# log4j2 trigger System.exit

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm basically trying to do the following :

- Whenever I get a fatal logged, log4j2 should automatically exit
- log4j2 should call System.exit after X amount of errors get logged

If log4j2 doesn't have this capability, is there anyway to put a callback hook on these logs?

Thanks!

Comment: have u tried any code

Comment: log4j is a logging framework, designed to gather and save diagnostic output from your application, without impacting its operation as little as possible. It cannot do what you need, you have to look for another tool/implement it yourself.

Comment: If you really need to do this, you could - for example - try reading the logs from an external script, and kill the app on certain conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to do this automatically. However, it would be trivial to create an Appender that calls System.exit(). Then all you need to do is set your configuration to log to that appender when a fatal message is logged.

You can also create a Filter that counts the number of error messages that are logged and then always returns NEUTRAL. Once the count is reached it would call System.exit().

All that said, this is not something I would ever want in a system I worked on.